# Unable to send message to IBM MQ

Tags: spring-boot, apache-camel, ibm-mq, activemq-artemis, jboss-eap-7

We are facing strange problem in our application. We are having three applications, say application A, application B and application C. Application A is a J2EE application deployed in JBoss EAP 7.2.0 which sends a message to ActiveMQ Artemis queue created in the same JBoss server. Application B is a middle-ware application written using Apache Camel which reads the message (which application A sent) from ActiveMQ Artemis queue, does some transformation and sends to a IBM MQ from which application C reads the message.

My issue is when the message is sent by Application A,the message is getting transformed correctly in application B but not sent to the IBM MQ, but when I am sending the same message to ActiveMQ Artemis queue (to which application A sends) using a demo client from my local environment, it is transformed and sent to IBM MQ and application C also picks that up successfully.

Can anyone give some idea why the message is not sent to IBM MQ when sent from application A? Is there some header which can prevent the message to be sent? Thanks in advance.

Comment: IBM MQ does not have full JMS support, at least I have encountered some issues when using non-default features. It will be a lot of guesswork to solve the problem without a stack trace and example messages.

Comment: But the message is being sent when I am sending from client application. This is complicating.

Comment: The demo application must be populating different default headers than application A. To solve this, I suggest you debug the message going out from application A, and compare it to the message going out from the client application.

Comment: The message bodies are exactly same, can you suggest which headers I need to check?

Comment: I could suggest something, but the odds of you even using the header I suggest would be very small. It will be like playing dart in the dark. Again, if you compare the headers generated from the different applications, you will in all likelihood have your answer.

Comment: What are the JMS exceptions and MQ reason code that application B receives when it fails to send the message to an IBM MQ queue?

Comment: I am printing the logs in server.log at INFO level and not able to find any response code either for the scenario of successful posting or failure posting. Is there any other log I should look at?

Comment: Take a look at the error logs in IBM MQ, to see what it didn't like about the message when it originates from Application A. I assume Both Application A and you client app are Java applications. Are they running the same version of Java and Artemis client libraries?